# set shadowsocks proxy on wsl2

Tags: proxy, windows-subsystem-for-linux, http-proxy, shadowsocks

I have followed these two links to set up apt-get proxy. https://github.com/microsoft/WSL/issues/6143 and https://askubuntu.com/questions/7470/how-to-run-sudo-apt-get-update-through-proxy-in-commandline meaning;

I edited `/etc/sudoers` to:

> Defaults env_keep = "http_proxy https_proxy ftp_proxy DISPLAY
> XAUTHORITY"

and set proxy like this:

> export HTTPS_PROXY="http://${hostip}:1080"
> export HTTPS_PROXY="http://${hostip}:1080"
> export https_proxy="http://${hostip}:1080"
> export http_proxy="http://${hostip}:1080"

but I still can't connect to my shadowsocks server. any thoughts?

Comment: How are you setting the `hostip` variable?  I don't see any reference to that in either of the two links you posted.

Comment: 'hostip' is set by windows

Comment: Not in my experience, no.  I might be missing something obvious, but a Google search for [wsl hostip](https://www.google.com/search?q=wsl%20hostip) doesn't seem to indicate this either.  Instead, you'll see a number of suggestions on how to retrieve the host ip.  Try `hostip=$(powershell.exe "(Test-Connection -ComputerName (hostname) -Count 1).IPV4Address.IPAddressToString")`.  There are some other, simpler methods (e.g. `yourwindowscomputername.local` or `yourwindowscomputername.mshome.net`), but they return the IP of the virtual NIC, and your proxy may not be bound to that address.

Answer (score 0):

If you want a VPN on your WSL just install `protonvpn`:

```
pip install protonvpn-cli
```

Comment: Congratulations on finding the solution yourself. However, considering that your answer revolves around a VPN, and your original question around the [shadowsocks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shadowsocks) encryption protocol, you may want to edit the answer to add more information on why you (seemingly) abandoned your original approach.

Comment: My initial question remains although I found a workaround that might be a remedy